# Date format '2024-01-19T18:33:16.000000000' not imputing in BigQuery using format - Field 'date' has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP

Tags: python, datetime, google-bigquery

I'm trying to move a dataframe from python, with a date column  format as `'2024-01-19T18:33:16.000000000'` to Bigquery. this column also has NaT values. But while pushing this in BigQuery, i have specified the column schema as 'DATETIME', but am getting the following error -

> Field 'date' has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP

What is the problem and how should it be solved? current datatype of date column is datetime64[ns]

Also, can someone specify what would the formatting of this date - `'2024-01-19T18:33:16.000000000'` be like? if i would like to play around with it by converting it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type) it states that the canonical format for Datetime type is:

```
civil_date_part[time_part]

civil_date_part:
    YYYY-[M]M-[D]D

time_part:
    { |T|t}[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.F]
```

where `[.F]: Up to six fractional digits (microsecond precision).`

In your case, `'2024-01-19T18:33:16.000000000'` contains 9 fractional digits. That's one of the errors you are facing.

You can check this by running the following query:

```
SELECT DATETIME('2024-01-19T18:33:16.000000000') as datetime
```

You will get: `Invalid datetime string "2024-01-19T18:33:16.000000000"`

However, removing the last 3 digits will work. Query result is: `2024-01-19T18:33:16`

My suggestion would be that you removed the last 3 digits in your python code before uploading it to BigQuery. For the `NaN` values, you have to convert them into a None format. There are different ways to do it, one simple could be:

`df['datetime_column_with_nan_values'] = df['datetime_column_with_nan_values'].replace({np.nan : None})`